# Google image-charts grid lines not responding to the chg value

Tags: image-charts

I am trying to implement a chart into my website using [image-charts](https://www.image-charts.com/), but no matter how I set the gridline spacing, the graph never works out the way I want it to be.

I read through [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts#grid-lines-chg-%5B-line,-bar,-radar,-scatter-%5D), and it says that you can use `chg=<x_axis_step_size>,<y_axis_step_size>` to set the grid size. I want the grid size to be 1x50. So I tried `chg=1,50` but it did not work.

This is my graph: https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lxy&chs=999x480&chd=t:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60|660,570,520,615,492,510,523,495,500,510,562,570,572,531,544,551,568,567,584,570,560,545,537,543,521,517,522,512,519,516,511,519,529,528,533,525,519,531,529,524,524,524,522,518,520,530,518,524,517,512,515,505,507,509,514,505,506,503,502,504,504|0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,60|0,492,528,612,648,324,492,636,456,492,444,528,396&chxl=0:|0|5|10|15|20|25|30|35|40|45|50|55|60&chco=ffbc8a,407bcb&chxt=x,y&chls=3|3&chdl=Overall|Last%205%20seconds&chdlp=t&chg=1,50

As you can see from the url, it ends with `chg=1,50`, but if you click on the link and look at the image, the grid space is 10x100. I also tried changing the values to values other than `1,50`, but the grid space always stays at 10x100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.*

[Image-Charts.com](https://www.image-charts.com) was created in 2016 to be *as close as possible* as the [now soon to be shutdown Google Image Charts API](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chart-api/rZtHTyYgyXI/z67NKmx7DAAJ).

Here is [our documentation regarding grid lines](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/grid-lines/).

As you will see per our documentation:

> Google Image charts use these two parameters to calculate how many x or y grid lines to show on the chart, we decided not to implement this feature as it was hard to use and error prone.

Thus the first two `chg` parameters are only used to enable/disable grid lines on `x` and `y` axis.